# How to Combine 2 Struct arrays in C

Tags: c

iv tried a lot of solutions to try to get this working (i.e using memcpy etc) I cant seem to find the issue, depending on what I try I either end up with gibberish or SEGV

iv spent a lot of time already googling and trying different ways, i still cant figure out why the arrays won't combine successfully

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>      
#include <unistd.h>

#define log_info printf
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    //size_t size;
} entry_t;


/* qsort struct comparison function (C-string field) */
static int struct_cmp_by_name(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    entry_t* ia = (entry_t*)a;
    entry_t* ib = (entry_t*)b;
    return strcmp(ia->name, ib->name);
    /* strcmp functions works exactly as expected from comparison function */
}

entry_t* get_item_entries(const char* dirpath, int* count)
{
    struct dirent* dent;
    char           buffer[512]; // fixed buffer

    int dfd = 0,
        n, r = 1;    // item counter, rounds to loop
    entry_t* p = NULL; // we fill this struct with items

loop:
    n = 0;
    printf("loop: %d, count:%d\n", r, *count);

    // try to open dir
    dfd = open(dirpath, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (dfd < 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid directory. (%s)\n", dirpath);
        *count = -1;
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("open(%s)\n", dirpath);
    }

    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    while (syscall(SYS_getdents, dfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != 0)
    {
        dent = (struct dirent*)buffer;

        while (dent->d_fileno)
        {   // skip `.` and `..`
            if (!strncmp(dent->d_name, "..", 2)
                || !strncmp(dent->d_name, ".", 1)) goto skip_dent;

            // deal with filtering outside of this function, we just skip .., .

            switch (r)
            {   // first round: just count items
            case 1:
            {
                // skip special cases
                if (dent->d_fileno == 0) goto skip_dent;

                break;
            }
            // second round: store filenames
            case 0: p[n].name = strdup(dent->d_name); break;
            }
            n++;

        skip_dent:

            dent = (struct dirent*)((void*)dent + dent->d_reclen);

            if (dent == (void*)&buffer[512]) break; // refill buffer
        }
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    }
    close(dfd);

    // on first round, calloc for our list
    if (!p)
    {   // now n holds total item count, note it
        p = calloc(n, sizeof(entry_t));
        *count = n;
    }

    // first round passed, loop
    r--; if (!r) goto loop;

    // report count
    printf("%d items at %p, from 1-%d\n", *count, (void*)p, *count);

    /* resort using custom comparision function */
    qsort(p, *count, sizeof(entry_t), struct_cmp_by_name);

    // report items
    //for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) log_error( "%s", p[i].name);

    return p;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    int HDD_count = -1;
    uint32_t total = -1;
    int   ext_count = -1;
    entry_t* e = NULL;

    entry_t  *HDD = get_item_entries("/mnt/f/n", &HDD_count);

    entry_t* ext = get_item_entries("/mnt/f/dls", &ext_count);

    total = ext_count + HDD_count;


        e = (entry_t*)malloc(sizeof *e * total);
        if (e != NULL)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < HDD_count; i++)
            {
                log_info("HDD[%i].name %s\n", i, HDD[i].name);
                e[i].name  = strdup(HDD[i].name);

            }

            for (int i = 1; i < ext_count; i++)
            {
                log_info("ext[%i].name %s\n", i, ext[i].name);
                e[i + HDD_count].name = strdup(ext[i].name);
            }

        }
        else
           printf("Failed to Allocate the Array");



    char tmp[256];

    int i = 1, j;
    for(j = 1; j <= total; j++)
    {   
    
        snprintf(&tmp[0], 255, "%s", e[ j].name);
        log_info("%i:%s\n", j , tmp);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see `goto`. Rewrite it without it. It is a banned keyword used in very specific very rare circumstances.

Comment: 1. What exactly do you mean by "fail to combine"? 2. Your program does a lot of things. Please reduce it into a [smaller reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Too much code, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @einpoklum iv now added the min.

Comment: @0___________  _"It is a banned keyword"_.  Banned is an overstatement, especially egregious to say that when you follow it up with a qualification that it is still used.

Comment: There is a lot code to review  to even figure out where you are trying to combine things.  It also does something file system specific that we cannot reproduce.  Minimize, implement error handling (get_item_entries can return NULL for instance).

Comment: Your loops in `main()` don't look right.  `for (int i = 1; i < HDD_count; i++)`.  You usually start at `i = 0`, as is, the first lop with not initialize `e[0]` and the 2nd loop will not initialize `e[HDD_count]` (and you will miss an entry from HDD and ext).

Comment: `uint32_t total = -1;` is not necessarily wrong but if you use an unsigned value 0 might make more sense or just initialize it to the sum when you need it: `uint32_t total = HDD_count + ext_count;`.  Check the return value of get_item_entries before using those counts.

Comment: @thebusybee: This is still far from minimal. For example: You're reading data from files. We don't have the files you're using. Can you not, for purposes of asking for our help, swap that out for fixed data, in constants? Or - is your problem in the reading of the data?

Comment: @einpoklum You meant to address the OP, not me, didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rewrite of a snippet of `main()` that I mentioned in my comment above:

```
    #define CHECK(p, msg) if(!(p)) { printf("%s:%d: %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, msg); return 1;}
    ...
    entry_t *HDD = get_item_entries("/mnt/f/n", &HDD_count);
    CHECK(HDD, "HDD failed to get entries");
    entry_t *ext = get_item_entries("/mnt/f/dls", &ext_count);
    CHECK(ext, "ext failed to get entries");
    uint32_t total = HDD_count + ext_count;
    entry_t *e = malloc(total * sizeof(*e));
    CHECK(e, "malloc failed");
    for(int i = 0; i < HDD_count; i++) {
        log_info("HDD[%i].name %s\n", i, HDD[i].name);
        e[i].name = strdup(HDD[i].name);
    }
    // write a function instead of duplicating code?
    for (int i = 0; i < ext_count; i++) {
        log_info("ext[%i].name %s\n", i, ext[i].name);
        e[HDD_count + i].name = strdup(ext[i].name);
    }
```

It looks like a short lived program, but I would still free the values from `strdup()` and `e` itself.